# Merge only one Feature branch changes to master

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge

I have a problem.

1. Create a Feature branch F1 from DEV
2. Make Changes in F1, commit the changes and merge F1 to DEV
3. Create a Feature F2 from DEV
4. Make Changes in F2, commit and merge F2 to DEV
5. Now the business decides they want only Feature F2 to migrate to PRODUCTION
6. So I am trying to merge F2 file changes to MASTER branch
7. I want only to merge the file changes I did in F2 to MASTER not to pick up the changes from F1

Is it possible? Can you please help me when I merge it is also picking up the changes from F1 to merge to MASTER.

Comment: But why you merge F1 to DEV at **step 4**, when you at this step only make changes in F2? Or do I get something wrong

Comment: We want that changes only in DEV/QA . But when business asks the particular feature to move to PROD we want to merge it to master and deploy to PROD(Order can be anything).

So stuck on how to do this approach. We want all the features in DEV/QA but only merge certain feature to PROD

Comment: As the question was asked, you only want to merge **one** feature-branch into `master`. Are you removed the feature-branch after merging in DEV? So if no, you can checkout the master branch and merge the feature-branch in master.

Comment: I think we need more information: 1.) I also have the same question as @SwissCodeMen. In Step 4, is that a typo? Shouldn't that say "...and merge **F2** to DEV"? 2.) Is your normal process to merge `DEV` to `MASTER` when you are ready to deploy? 3.) Does your workflow allow for having a `hotfix` or `release` branch? 4.) Is `DEV` a throwaway branch that you reset periodically, or is it a persisted branch like `MASTER`?

Comment: 1) Yes its a typo , I corrected it
2) We want to merge Feature branch to DEV first and then when business wants the feature we want Feature to merge to MASTER/RELEASE
3)Yes we can allow release branch
4) DEV branch will have all the features developed by different team members but when business want a feature we would only want that feature to be present. Say I have F1,F2,F3 in DEV and business says move F2 we want that to move only.

Answer (score 2):

## Is it possible?

Yes, as long as you didn't have conflicts to resolve when merging F2 into DEV:

on `master`branch run `git merge F2`, since as you describe it, that branch would contain all F2 developments, but not F1. If the branch F2 does not exist anymore, you can replace it with the hash of the commit where F2 pointed to before merging into dev: `git merge <last-f2-commit>`

## Is it a good idea to work like this?

No, as different developments (F1, F2) will sooner or later interact with one another, and so you are moving to production a code that has not been tested as such: F1+F2 has been tested, F2 alone has not.

Feature toggles (or feature flags) might be a good approach here: allowing you to "disable F1" for production. This would also allow your testers to test "F2 only" before going into production. This will also allow you to move further, allowing some refactoring etc.